# Why can't you migrate question with bounty from MSE to OR?

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, bounty, migration

I wanted to to migrate my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246019/why-the-optimal-value-that-minimizes-a-function-does-not-satisfy-condition here so I flagged  my question to contact moderators but instead got the response

> Wait until the bounty is over. If after that questions remain, ask them anew there. Link back to this site.

Can moderators from this site do something about it?

Answer (score 4):

There are at least a couple of impediments to doing what you ask.  Migration is a form of closure for a Question within a Community, at least in the sense of making it unanswerable there.  Questions with bounties are immune from closure so that no one is deprived of the opportunity to compete for the bounty.

Also your request takes the form of transferring the bounty *with* the Question in migration.  This amounts to transferring reputation points from one Community to another.  I don't believe there is any analog for this in StackExchange software functionality, and purists might easily object to permitting such transfers as the Communities are expected to be separate missions.  A mature Community and a private beta Community present an even more compelling picture for separation.

But I do find that the idea is novel.

Comment: Another barrier is that it is not possible to migrate any question to a site in private beta.

Comment: @Discretelizard why?

Comment: @user441848 I cannot find a specific reason from SE on meta. (although it is interesting that this answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258601/) notes that migration to private beta is "rarely, if ever". I think that is consistent with the current situation: even site moderators cannot do this, but perhaps staff or CM's can) I can think of a few reason of my own, however: a private beta is, well, private. The other site is public. Changing the visibility of a question from public to private seems strange. (even though this is only a barrier for people without an account)

Comment: @user441848 If you'd like to have a better answer to that question, I suggest you ask on [meta.se].

Comment: It may not be allowable under SE, but to me it would be reasonable to allow tmigration of a question if the bounty does not go with it - that way, there would be no transfer of reputation across sites - and if the OP (not another user) offered the bounty. So the OP would lose the bounty. As for depriving other people of the right to earn the bounty, tough boogies, it was the OP who"spent" the reputation for the bounty and now chooses to forego it in orfer to migrate the question.